# TimeSpan.ToString() return string like (d:hh:mm:ss)

Tags: c#, timespan

```
TimeSpan Ts = new TimeSpan(5, 4, 3, 2);
return Ts.ToString("?");
```

What expression should I replace with a question mark to get this format:
***5d:4h:3m:2s*** ?

Comment: you can accomplish this using your code and formatting 
`TimeSpan Ts = new TimeSpan(5, 4, 3, 2);
            var RetValue = string.Format("{0}d:{1}h:{2}m:{3}s",Ts.Days,Ts.Hours,Ts.Milliseconds, Ts.Seconds);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(5, 4, 3, 2);
string str = timeSpan.ToString(@"d\d\:h\h\:m\m\:s\s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) on how to format `TimeSpan`s.

Though note that negative `TimeSpan`s cannot be distinguished from positive ones. They appear like they have been [negated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.negate.aspx). Therefor `-new TimeSpan(5,4,3,2)` will still show as `5d:4h:3m:2s`. If you want negative numbers to display, you should format your own numbers though the properties of `TimeSpan`.

Comment: There is no need to escape all characters of your format string. Escaping \. and \: is enough.

Comment: Mosh wanted parts postfixed with its corresponding part, so for his usecase its required. If you just want `12:34:45`, then escaping is not required.

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I did not read the question the the very end.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by using your current code

```
TimeSpan Ts = new TimeSpan(5, 4, 3, 2);
var RetValue = string.Format("{0}d:{1}h:{2}m:{3}s",
    Ts.Days,
    Ts.Hours,
    Ts.Minutes,
    Ts.Seconds);
```

yields this as a formatted result `"5d:4h:0m:2s"`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
"d'd:'h'h:'m'm:'s's'"
```

Found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

Comment: This is incredibly helpful (especially in gridview). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a TimeSpan Extension method that will hide empty large time parts.

```
public static string ToShortString(this TimeSpan Ts)
{
    if(Ts.TotalDays > 1d)
        return Ts.ToString("d'd:'h'h:'m'm:'s's'");

    if(Ts.TotalHours > 1d)
        return Ts.ToString("h'h:'m'm:'s's'");

    if(Ts.TotalMinutes > 1d)
        return Ts.ToString("m'm:'s's'");

    if(Ts.TotalSeconds > 1d)
        return Ts.ToString("s's'");

    if(Ts.TotalMilliseconds > 1d)
        return Ts.ToString("fffffff'ms'");

    return Ts.ToString();
}
```